# Is there a way to specify the Date Format used with SQLServer Management Object Scripting

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

When I'm generating my database scripts for my project I'd like to manage the date format that is used in the comments in the SQLScript.

I have my regional settings set to Australian format, but they seem to be disregarded.

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management
...
        Dim scr As Smo.Scripter
        Dim opt As Smo.ScriptingOptions

...
        opt = New Smo.ScriptingOptions
        opt.???? =  //Is there something that I can set to control the date?
        opt.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII
        opt.DriAll = True
        opt.ClusteredIndexes = True
        opt.Default = True
        opt.Indexes = True
        opt.IncludeHeaders = True
        opt.AppendToFile = True
```

Results in a script with comments that look like this... Note the date is in US Format.

```
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AAAExampleData]    Script Date: 06/17/2009 10:08:38 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

I know that the Comments are only for readability, but I'd like complete control over my output.

If it's not possible, please just say that.

Comment: Bug lodged on Connect as 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=467690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you report this to Microsoft as a bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/. Search first to see if someone else has reported this. It's likely that someone who is not an English speaker will have reported this; you're only looking to change the order of fields, others need the language and character set to change!

Once you've entered a bug report, please edit your question to include a link to it. That we, interested parties can vote on your bug report.